# Cannot exec into nginx container to debug, get is restarting, wait until the container is running

Tags: docker, nginx

I have an nginx service in my docker-compose. I'm trying to use this to obtain my first ssl cert from lets encrypt. It's not working and I cannot seem to exec into the container to check the conf settings.

[I'm using envsubt](http://docs.docker.oeynet.com/samples/library/nginx/#using-environment-variables-in-nginx-configuration) and I suspect this is my issue, but since I cannot get into the container I cannot check. My set up:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./templates:/etc/nginx/templates
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
      - ./entry-scripts/40-reload.sh:/docker-entrypoint.d/40-reload.sh
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - collabora
    env_file: .env
```

File `40-reload.sh`

```
# reload nginx config every 60 seconds in case certs get updated
while :; do
  sleep 60
  echo reloading
  nginx -s reload
done &

nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

File `.templates/default.conf.template` which I place in `/etc/nginx/templates`:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/${COLLABORA_DOMAIN}/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/${COLLABORA_DOMAIN}/privkey.pem;
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
server_tokens off;

server {
    
    listen          80;
    server_name     www.${COLLABORA_DOMAIN} ${COLLABORA_DOMAIN};
    
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }
    
    return 301 https://${COLLABORA_DOMAIN}$request_uri;
}

server {
    
    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name     www.${COLLABORA_DOMAIN} ${COLLABORA_DOMAIN}
    return 301 $scheme://${COLLABORA_DOMAIN}$request_uri;

}


server {
    
    listen          443 ssl;
    server_name     ${COLLABORA_DOMAIN};
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://collabora:9980;
        access_log off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    
    # static files
    location ^~ /loleaflet {
        proxy_pass http://collabora:9980;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    # WOPI discovery URL
        location ^~ /hosting/discovery {
            proxy_pass http://collabora:9980;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }

    # Capabilities
    location ^~ /hosting/capabilities {
        proxy_pass http://collabora:9980;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    # main websocket
    location ~ ^/lool/(.*)/ws$ {
        proxy_pass http://collabora:9980;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
    }

    # download, presentation and image upload
    location ~ ^/lool {
        proxy_pass http://collabora:9980;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    # Admin Console websocket
    location ^~ /lool/adminws {
        proxy_pass http://collabora:9980;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
        }
}
```

When I run with `docker-compose up -d nginx` I can see:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                          PORTS     NAMES
08e8279e91a0   nginx:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   17 minutes ago   Restarting (1) 19 seconds ago             collabora_nginx_1
```

But I cannot get inside to see the conf settings:

```
docker-compose exec nginx /bin/bash
Error response from daemon: Container 08e8279e91a081da976d1ea3df7dfe33974744959fe8441eca365ffabc343d53 is restarting, wait until the container is running
```

I'd like to get inside the container and run `nginx -T` to verify my conf variables.

How can I get into the container to see the conf variables?

Comment: As you can see the error it's stating that the container is not up and running. It's still in restarting state. Restart the container and check again

Comment: Something might have corrupted your container. Starting a fresh container should ideally do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to restart the container and check the status of the container

   `docker restart <your_container_name>`
2. If the status is running then login to the container using `exec` command

   `docker exec -it <your_container_name/id> bash`